# Como Criar um filtro entre duas dropdowns usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Eu tenho duas dropdowns (estado e cidades)

no select "estado"

eu tenho os options de dois estados ex:

```
<select name="state">
         <option value="NY">New York</option>
         <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
 </select>

<select name="city">
         <option value="NY">Norwich</option>
         <option value="NY">Younkers </option>

         <option value="LA">Beverly Hills </option>
         <option value="LA">Santa Monica</option>
 </select>
```

o que eu preciso é filtrar via jquery o dropdown "city" usando o Value do "state" ou seja quando eu seleccionar no Estado o "New York " automaticamente no dropdown "city" so deve aparecer as cidades que possuem o value NY..

por favor....

Answer (score 2):

Seria legal que enviasse uma requisição para sua aplicação retornar a segunda lista no evento de mudança da primeira lista. Faça assim:

```js
$("#PRIMEIRO_COMBOBOX").on('change', function(){
       $.ajax({
         type: method,
         url: url,
         data: data,
         success: function(response) {
             //Aqui popula seu segundo combobox com o retorno da aplicação  
         } 
       }); 
   });
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.